# How to add space after each byte in python

Tags: python

I have a file which contains a set of lines, each of line includes an hexadecimal number. I need to add space after each byte. For example:

```
84dd251ae078d70a55ead31b4e8c3acd

84 dd 25 1a e0 78 d7 0a 55 ea d3 1b 4e 8c 3a cd
```

After that modification, I want to save the result in a new file: I tried to do that:

```
Srcpath ='File_Without_Space'
Destpath ='Files_With_Space'
with open(Srcpath, 'r') as f:
    with open(Destpath, 'w') as fp:
        for key in f:
            print(key)
            key_Separated=[key[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(key), 2)]
            print (key_Separated)
            fp.write(str(key_Separated) +'\n')
```

Howeer the result is:

```
['3c', 'd4', '20', '74', '81', '04', '49', '8d', '9b', 'f0', '66', '99', 'dd', 'a3', 'ee', 'd1', '\n']
```

instead of being:

```
84 dd 25 1a e0 78 d7 0a 55 ea d3 1b 4e 8c 3a cd
```

How could I please resolve this problem?

Comment: You produced a list; now just join it with a space: `rejoined = ' '.join(key_Separated)`.

Comment: You only need join your resulting list: `" ".join(key_Separated)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `re` module to get 2 elements at a time, which returns array and then join them with space

```
import re

....
print(key)
key_Separated = " ".join(re.findall('([0-9a-f]{2}|[0-9a-f])', s))
print (key_Separated)
```

Example

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "84dd251ae078d70a55ead31b4e8c3acd"
>>> " ".join(re.findall('([0-9a-f]{2}|[0-9a-f])', s))
'84 dd 25 1a e0 78 d7 0a 55 ea d3 1b 4e 8c 3a cd'

>>> s = "84dd251ae078d70a55ead31b4e8c3acda"
>>> " ".join(re.findall('([0-9a-f]{2}|[0-9a-f])', s))
'84 dd 25 1a e0 78 d7 0a 55 ea d3 1b 4e 8c 3a cd a'

>>> s = "84dd251ae078d70a55ead31b4e8c3acda1"
>>> " ".join(re.findall('([0-9a-f]{2}|[0-9a-f])', s))
'84 dd 25 1a e0 78 d7 0a 55 ea d3 1b 4e 8c 3a cd a1'
```

Comment: However, if you have a trailing hex character, this would just ignore it - that might be an indication of invalid input... Plus other factors such as not valid capture characters that don't happen to be part of the input etc...

Comment: @JonClements good point. But OP mentioned it will contain only hex part

Comment: Always good to be robust where possible when the tools are easily available